# DC/DC Converter Output Power Rating

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost

Looking at chips such as

[AP6502A](https://datasheet.octopart.com/AP6502ASP-13-Diodes-Inc.-datasheet-46750874.pdf)
[TPS5430](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps5430.pdf)

The output capability is rated in peak and continuous current. Why are they not rated in terms of power? What output voltage is this current rating for?

As for example a rating of 3A at:

5V = 15W
12V = 36W

Comment: Because current is more often a more meaningful physical quantity to most designers. Look. At Power Integrations if you want ICs listed in useable output power figures.

Comment: But the power would provide the available current for the required output voltage which would be more useful as it can be calculated based on application?

Comment: Perhaps to you, but you need to live with the fact that most designers will look for an output current and you need to adapt to that or work your way around the problem, probably by an excel sheet to calculate the output power for you.

Comment: But output current is meaningless without knowing the voltage. Are you trying to say that the converter in question is rated for 3A at any output voltage?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @AndyWest: Your question should use the chip part numbers in the hyperlink anchor text rather than "CHIP1" and "CHIP2". You do get credit for linking to actual datasheets though and not an Amazon or Ali-Express catalog page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [TPS543x 3-A, Wide Input Range, Step-Down Converter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps5430.pdf) datasheet we get the internal block diagram.

[image]

*Figure 1. The block diagram shows only the MOSFET (2) in the power path.*

This is a form of switching power supply. Their great efficiency comes from the fact that the switching transistor (the MOSFET at (2)) is either fully off or fully on.

- When fully off I = 0 so the power dissipated in the MOSFET, \$P = VI = V \cdot 0 = 0 \ \text W \$.
- When fully on I = 3 A (max for this chip) and the voltage drop across the transistor will be about 450 mV (see 6.5, R<sub>DS(on)</sub>). In this state \$ P = VI = 450m \times 3 = 1.5 \ \text W \$.

Note that the supply voltage never enters the calculations. The limiting factor is the MOSFET current handling and thermal management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see now why my original train of thought was incorrect. Based on what you've said, the only time the output voltage has to be taken into account in the power calculations is if the Inductor is integrated into the package ie https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltm8063.html which explains why that device defines current output for a specific voltage

Answer (score 1):

The current a switching supply delivers is what determines the stress on (particularly) the switching transistors.  It doesn't matter what the load voltage is, all that matters to the chip is the current and the drop across the device.

Of course, your supply cares...the more power you supply, the more you have to pull from the source.